# Three.js Position Rendered STL file in the center of screen

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a rendered STL file from Thingiverse displaying with Three.js using the THREE.STLLoader() load the source files.
My problem is I don't know how to position it in the center of the screen and can only do so by adjusting the roation properties which I'm modifying using the event touch coordinates.
I'm trying to get the object in the center of the screen and roatate from the center when I move my finger over the screen.

This is what I currently have, any help would be appreciated:

```
var container, stats;

var camera, scene, renderer;
var stlMesh;

var mesh, geometry;

var loader;

var directionalLight;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var zoom = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

// Ejecta; Added for touch controls:
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.2, 100);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    scene.add(camera);

    // light
    var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

    scene.add(dirLight);

    // STL
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load(window.filePath, function(geometry) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0xffff00,
            specular: 0x111111,
            shininess: 200
        });
        stlMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        stlMesh.position.set(0, -0.25, 0.6);

        stlMesh.rotation.set(0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
        stlMesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        stlMesh.castShadow = true;
        stlMesh.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add(stlMesh);
    });

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0); // the default
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function getCentroid(mesh) {
    mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var boundingBox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox;

    var size = boundingBox.size();
    console.log(size.x, size.y, size.z);

    var x0 = boundingBox.min.x;
    var x1 = boundingBox.max.x;
    var y0 = boundingBox.min.y;
    var y1 = boundingBox.max.y;
    var z0 = boundingBox.min.z;
    var z1 = boundingBox.max.z;

    var bWidth = (x0 > x1) ? x0 - x1 : x1 - x0;
    var bHeight = (y0 > y1) ? y0 - y1 : y1 - y0;
    var bDepth = (z0 > z1) ? z0 - z1 : z1 - z0;

    var centroidX = x0 + (bWidth / 2) + mesh.position.x;
    var centroidY = y0 + (bHeight / 2) + mesh.position.y;
    var centroidZ = z0 + (bDepth / 2) + mesh.position.z;

    return mesh.geometry.centroid = {
        x: centroidX,
        y: centroidY,
        z: centroidZ
    };
}

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

// Ejecta; Added for touch controls
function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
    //mouseX = ( event.touches[0].clientX - windowHalfX ) * 4;
    //mouseY = ( event.touches[0].clientY - windowHalfY ) * 4;
    //mouseX = event.touches[0].clientX-180
    //mouseY = event.touches[0].clientY-180

    if (event.touches.length == 1) {
        // Roation Action
        mouseX = degInRad(event.touches[0].clientX)
        mouseY = degInRad(event.touches[0].clientY)
    } else if (event.touches.length == 2) {
        positionY1 = event.touches[0].clientY
        positionY2 = event.touches[1].clientY
        if (positionY2 > positionY1) {
            t1 = positionY1
            positionY1 = positionY2
            positionY2 = t1
        }

        zoom = (positionY1 - positionY2) / window.innerHeight
        zoom = zoom > 0.9 ? 0.9 : zoom
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function degInRad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function render() {
    var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();
    // OLD
    //camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
    //camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

    //camera.lookAt(stlMesh.position);
    //scene.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );

    // NEW
    stlMesh.rotation.y = mouseX;
    stlMesh.rotation.x = mouseY;
    //stlMesh.rotation.y = 4.790928796724434;
    //stlMesh.rotation.x = 3.3073989325292543;
    //stlMesh.position.z = camera.position.z*zoom
    //console.log(stlMesh.position.x, stlMesh.position.y)
    //console.log("Z: "+stlMesh.position.z)

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I seem to have found the answer after reading through the Three.js sourcecode, the key was to 'center' the geometry before creating the mesh.
Here's my new THREE.STLoader(); load method:

```
// STL
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load(window.filePath, function ( geometry ) {
    geometry.center()
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
    stlMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    camera.position.z = geometry.boundingBox.size().z+300
    //stlMesh.translateY()
    scene.add(stlMesh);
});
```